# One to one function behaviour

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Like in pigeon hole principle , if one set of objects(S1) has more items than others set of objects(S2) and we try to fit that S1 in S2 ( that is mapping the values of S1 to S2 , we end up getting same value for atleast two value in larger set(S1) (ie for atleast two index i1 and i2 in S1 they have same value index in S2 ) .
Now in real number theory, one to one function like y=(x/2) , if x lies from [a,b] then y will be between [a/2,b/2], so is y=(x/2) one to one , or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking a question that has caused a lot of consternation over the centuries.

If two sets $X$ and $Y$ have different cardinalities, with $\vert X\vert >\vert Y\vert$, then any mapping $f:X\to Y$ from the larger to the smaller must be non-injective: 
$$
\exists x_1,x_2\in X \, \big((x_1\neq x_2) \& \left(f(x_1)=f(x_2)\right)\big).$$
This is, as you note, the *pigeonhole principle*.

So, what happens when we consider $f:[0,2]\to [0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=x/2$?  This function is clearly injective: 
$$\left(\frac{x_1}{2}=\frac{x_2}{2}\right)\Rightarrow (x_1=x_2).$$
So, what is going on?  Well, the answer given by Cantor is that despite that fact that $[0,2]\supsetneq [0,1]$, these two sets *have the same cardinality*.  In fact, this insight leads to the central definition that undergirds all of modern set theory:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are two sets and there exists a bijection $f:X\to Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ *have the same cardinality* (written $\vert X\vert=\vert Y\vert$).

Relatedly:

> If an injection from $X$ to $Y$ exists, then we can say $\vert X\vert\leq \vert Y\vert.$

This second definition allows us to conclude that 
$$X\subseteq Y \Rightarrow \vert X\vert \leq \vert Y\vert.$$

Now, things get tricky when one notes that "infinite" is *not* a cardinality according to this definition!  It is provable that there exist pairs of infinite sets between which no bijection can exist!  Famously, Cantor's diagonalization argument showed that $\vert \mathbb{Q}\vert\neq\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$.  More generally, no set has the same cardinality as its power set.

This is a good thing really, since it tells us that defining cardinality in terms of bijections is not trivial.  The fact that $\big\vert [0,1]\big\vert=\big\vert [0,2]\big\vert$ is not merely a consequence of the fact that both sets are infinite: there is a more meaningful relationship between the sets than that.

---

FYI The Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem is an important tool for showing that sets have the same cardinality: it states that if there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$, and another injection from $Y$ to $X$, then there must be a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.  Equivalently:
$$
\big(\vert X\vert\leq\vert Y\vert \& \vert Y\vert\leq\vert X\vert\big) \Rightarrow \vert X\vert=\vert Y\vert$$

Comment: you understood my question right .But when things get infinite , then also there are numbers  in number system like(R) , why we ignore that ?

Comment: well can you provide me more links for understanding stuff you just gave ?

Comment: Well, since cardinality is defined in terms of bijections and injections, it is pretty clear that the pigeonhole principle can be applied to infinite sets, but is essentially a property of cardinalities. The compression going from $[0,2]$ to $[0,1]$ is real, but it is not a feature of cardinality, and so is not related to the pigeon hole principle.  If you want to understand that compression, you need to consider *measures*. For links, just google "infinite cardinals and pigeonhole principle": there are lots of relevant links there.